# Using metric.Mean() in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am working through a tensorflow tutorial in Google Colabs and have run everything as the tutorial specifies in the link below:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough

and I am running the following piece of code:

```
## Note: Rerunning this cell uses the same model variables

# keep results for plotting
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []

num_epochs = 201

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  epoch_loss_avg = tf.metrics.Mean()
  epoch_accuracy = tf.metrics.Accuracy()

  # Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
    # Optimize the model
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
                              global_step)

    # Track progress
    epoch_loss_avg(loss_value)  # add current batch loss
    # compare predicted label to actual label
    epoch_accuracy(tf.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), y)

  # end epoch
  train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
  train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())

  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(epoch,
                                                                epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                                epoch_accuracy.result()))
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.metrics' has no attribute 'Mean'
```

From what I understand they are trying to do in the code is assign the function for tf.metrics.Mean() to epoch_loss_avg and then apply it further down in epoch_loss_avg(loss_value). So I am thinking maybe something has changed in Tensorflow since this tutorial was written, so I tried rewritting it as below:

```
## Note: Rerunning this cell uses the same model variables

# Keep results for plotting
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_result = []

num_epochs = 201

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  #epoch_loss_avg = tf.metrics.Mean()
  #epoch_accuracy = tf.metrics.Accuracy()

  # Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
    # Optimize the model
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
                             global_step)

    # Track progress
    mean_temp = tf.metrics.mean(loss_value) # Add current batch loss
    # Compare the predicted label to actual label
    acc_temp = tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.argmax(model(x), axis = 1, output_type = tf.int32), y)

  # End epoch
  train_loss_results.append(mean_temp)
  train_accuracy_results.append(acc_temp)

  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:,3f}, Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(epoch,
                                                               epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                               epoch_accuracy.result()))
```

Where the function is just run directly, but now I am getting another error message:

```
RuntimeError: tf.metrics.mean is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
```

So my question is, is there another way of writing this to get the same result and is my explanation of what is going on correct and if not what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in the tutoiral -- https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/383#issuecomment-450395276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to work with Eager Execution, you need to change `tf.metrics.Mean` and `tf.metrics.Accuracy` to:

```
epoch_loss_avg = tf.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean()
epoch_accuracy = tf.contrib.eager.metrics.Accuracy()
```

and also `tf.Variable` to:

```
global_step = tf.contrib.eager.Variable(0)
```

> From what I understand they are trying to do in the code is assign the function for tf.metrics.Mean() to epoch_loss_avg and then apply it further down in epoch_loss_avg(loss_value).

Yes, in line `epoch_loss_avg = tf.metrics.Mean()` they create the operation to calculate the mean and then they accumulate the losses over the batches in line `epoch_loss_avg(loss_value)`. So, at the end of the epoch we will have an average loss considering all batches from the dataset, which then results in the loss for the epoch (line `epoch_loss_avg.result()`).

About the second error: [`tf.metrics.mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean) raises a `RuntimeError` if eager execution is enabled, as you saw. You need to use `tf.contrib.eager.metrics` instead.